# 2 dropdown select boxes "from - to" allow user to select only values bigger than what selected in the "from" dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two dropdown boxes in my form. It lets user to choose from a range of values to make a search. However because it is a from - to system, I do not want the value of the `from` to be bigger than the value of the `to`. It can be equal though.

This restriction I can check it using PHP after the form is submitted. My goal is to disable choosing or hide the values that do not fulfill the above logic.

Maybe if the `1800` from `from` is selected, the values lower than `1800` to be hidden from the dropdown `to` and vice - versa.

How to do this using javascript, jQuery? Thank you.

A **second workaround** would be, if the value of `to` is smaller than the value of `from`, an alert box should be ok and return the `to` value to the next bigger value of `from` or something..

```
   <select class="form-control" name="from" >

                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
                <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
                <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
                <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>
                <option value="1800">1800 cc</option>
                <option value="2000">2000 cc</option>
                <option value="2500">2500 cc</option>
                <option value="3000">3000 cc</option>
                <option value="3500">3500 cc</option>
                <option value="4000">4000 cc</option>

   </select>

   <select class="form-control" name="to" >

                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
                <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
                <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
                <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>
                <option value="1800">1800 cc</option>
                <option value="2000">2000 cc</option>
                <option value="2500">2500 cc</option>
                <option value="3000">3000 cc</option>
                <option value="3500">3500 cc</option>
                <option value="4000">4000 cc</option>

   </select>
```

Comment: It is better to include code that you have tried and describe what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that fits your needs:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7He9/2)

```
$('select[name=from]').on('change', function(){
    var self = this;
    $('select[name=to]').find('option').prop('disabled', function(){
        return this.value && this.value < self.value && self.value
    });
});

$('select[name=to]').on('change', function(){
    var self = this;
    $('select[name=from]').find('option').prop('disabled', function(){
        return this.value && this.value > self.value && self.value
    });
});
```

Comment: You should check that SELECT as value selected too, see: http://jsfiddle.net/q7He9/2/  Otherwise, selecting default value will bring some kind of 'bug'. BTW, if this answer helped you, then accept it to close question

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" name="from" id="from" >

                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
                <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
                <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
                <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>
                <option value="1800">1800 cc</option>
                <option value="2000">2000 cc</option>
                <option value="2500">2500 cc</option>
                <option value="3000">3000 cc</option>
                <option value="3500">3500 cc</option>
                <option value="4000">4000 cc</option>

   </select>

   <select class="form-control" name="to" id="to">

                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <option value="1000">1000 cc</option>
                <option value="1200">1200 cc</option>
                <option value="1400">1400 cc</option>
                <option value="1600">1600 cc</option>
                <option value="1800">1800 cc</option>
                <option value="2000">2000 cc</option>
                <option value="2500">2500 cc</option>
                <option value="3000">3000 cc</option>
                <option value="3500">3500 cc</option>
                <option value="4000">4000 cc</option>

   </select>

<script>
$("#from").change(function(){
   var to = +$(this).val();
   $("#to option").each(function(){
       if ($(this).val() < to)
       {
          $(this).hide();
       }
       else
       {
          $(this).show();
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution for all workarouds

```
$('select[name=to]').on('change', function(){
var self = this;

var fromvalue=$('select[name=from]').find('option:selected').val();

if(self.value<fromvalue)
{
    alert('to is smaller than the value of from');

    $("#ddlto option").each(function() {
  if(fromvalue < $(this).val()) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
       return false;
  }                        
    });

}
```

});

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
  This will work :-

  $("#from").on("change", function () {
   var fromVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

   $("#to option").each(function () {
     if ($(this).val() < fromVal)
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
     else
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");

     });

 });

  $("#to").on("change", function () {
  var toVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

      $("#from option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() > toVal)
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");

       });

  });

 You can accept the answer if it helps you ;)
```